# syslog-ng modification issue for unix socket

Tags: linux, centos, syslog, unix-sockets, syslog-ng

I am having issue researching the right way to go about a problem. The problem is the syslog-ng file in the salt master server at the moment only enforces unix-stream as follows:

```
source s_sys {
        file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
        unix-stream ("/dev/log");
        internal();
};
source s_remote {
        udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
};
```

but now we want the new Centos-7 backup servers to have unix-dgram. So now I have a dilemma either to change this line to unix-dgram and wait to see if highstating with this config will have an issue when salt enforces unix-dgram on all our servers but I would very much like to add both the conditions in the salt config files. I researched a bit but could not find anything related in which both dgram and stream are used in the same config file.

Is there a way to do both?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
The issue is fixed. It looks something like this:

```
source s_sys {
   file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: ")); 
{%- if syslogng.osfinger == "CentOS Linux-7" %}
   unix-dgram ("/dev/log"); {%- else %}
   unix-stream ("/dev/log"); {%- endif %}
   internal();
   # udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));  };
```